# Ubuntu settings mess up after trying Kubuntu

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, indicator, fonts

I am trying Kubuntu on my computer, but then I come back again to Unity and when I do, configuration keeps some of KDE's settings:

- General window and indicator fonts are smaller and thinner; they're also black with dark background.
- Several indicator icons are missing, e.g. keyboard input, messaging available status, and calendar icon. Others are switched to KDE style, e.g. wifi, online status, and LibreOffice icons.
- And I noticed the keyboard shortcut for switching input, is still set but doesn't work.

I'm wondering how I can switch these back. Maybe each at a time, or maybe all at once.

Thanks and have a good day.  This is Ubuntu 14.04.